# Click button to add additional text fields not working

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have a poll system where users are able to create polls. Each poll must have at least two options, with the ability to add up to four.

Right now, I have a collection view cell for each text field, and I load 2 of these cells into the poll's collection view intially.

When a button is clicked, I want to add another one of this collection view cells so it shows another text field.

However, for whatever reason, if I type text into the first and second text fields, and then add two more collection view cells, it adds one text field below the second one and one text field above the first one, when it should simply be appending them all to the bottom.

Here is a visual of what's happening:

```
+----------------------+
| First text           |
+----------------------+

+----------------------+
| Second text          |
+----------------------+

Add field button
```

When I click the add field button twice, this happens:

```
+----------------------+
|                      |
+----------------------+

+----------------------+
| First text           |
+----------------------+

+----------------------+
| Second text          |
+----------------------+

+----------------------+
|                      |
+----------------------+
```

And I have no idea why it's doing this and it's driving me insane.

Here is my code (cut out the stuff that's not important):

```
// Holds the total number of poll options (initially 2, up to 4)
var numPollOptions: Int = 2

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return numPollOptions
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "NewPollOptionCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as? NewPollOptionCollectionViewCell else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of NewPollOptionCollectionViewCell.")
    }
        
    cell.presentingViewController = self
    cell.initialize(indexPath: indexPath)
        
    return cell
}

@IBAction func onAddPollOptionButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    self.numPollOptions += 1

    // Allow no more than 4 poll options
    if (numPollOptions >= 4) {
        addPollOptionButton.isHidden = true
    }
    
    self.pollCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: What is going on in `itemForRow`?

Comment: @vadian I updated the code to show

Comment: can you post your NewPollOptionCollectionViewCell class?

Comment: What happens in cell.initialize ?? This is where correspondence between indexPath and cell contents happens

Comment: If you just want to append instead of reloading the entire collectionView, you can just user `insertItems`. Eg: ` self.numPollOptions += 1
pollCollectionView.insertItems(at: [IndexPath(row: numPollOptions - 1, section: .zero)])
`